# Multiplying items in a range by an integer in Python

Tags: python, integer, range

I'm very new to stack overflow and python so please bear with me. I am trying to write a code that will output:

```
0 x 8 = 0
1 x 8 = 8
2 x 8 = 16
3 x 8 = 24
4 x 8 = 32
5 x 8 = 40
6 x 8 = 48
7 x 8 = 56
8 x 8 = 64
9 x 8 = 72
```

I have searched the internet and tried the following:

```
x=(int(z)*8 for z in range(10))
print(str(z) + 'x 8 = ' + str(x))
```

Which prompts error messages:

```
"TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list"
"NameError: name 'z' is not defined"
```

I have tried this using 'item' instead of 'z', with no luck.

I know this is a very basic task but all solutions I can find online are the same as the invalid code I already have. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: `z` is not defined in the second line because it's only defined in the scope of `for`, which is only the first line.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the variable `z` is only defined on your first line (within the context of the loop) and is not accessible to the other lines of your code. Instead you will want to loop through the values and perform the operation and printing on each item.

```
for z in range(10):
    print '{0} x 8 = {1}'.format(z, z * 8)

# 0 x 8 = 0
# 1 x 8 = 8
# 2 x 8 = 16
# 3 x 8 = 24
# 4 x 8 = 32
# 5 x 8 = 40
# 6 x 8 = 48
# 7 x 8 = 56
# 8 x 8 = 64
# 9 x 8 = 72
```

The other alternative is to store the multiplication results in `x` (as you have already done) and then loop through that to display each of them using `enumerate` to get the index.

```
x = [z * 8 for z in range(10)]
for k,value in enumerate(x):
    print '{0} x 8 = {1}'.format(k, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x=(int(z)*8 for z in range(10))
print("\n".join(str(z) + ' x 8 = ' + str(y) for z, y in zip(range(10), x)))
```

`x` is the list of `8` multiplications. You then iterate over the list using a `for` loop and get every pair using the `zip()` function. You then join it with `\n` designating newlines.